# I got an error in a code which is related to NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with NumPy Array but I got an error.

I am running that code with Pycharm and getting error

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,5,8,3])

l1 = arr.argsort()[-3][::-1]
print(l1)
```

Comment: What are your trying to do indexing with `[-3][::-1]`?

Comment: `arr.argsort()[-3]` is an int so trying to get an item by index from this object can't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is happening because you are trying to index a number. You cannot do that.

If what you are trying to do is get the third to last element in a sorted and reversed array, you need this:

```
l1 = arr.argsort()[::-1][-3]
```

If you are just trying to reverse the sorted the array, just the `argsort` portion is enough.